# Ensure Input Contains at least 5 Digits

Tags: html, forms

I've build a small app that requires a zipcode. We can also accept a city and a zipcode. But no matter what I want there to always be a zipcode or atleast 5 digits entered.

How can I do that?

Here's where I am now:

```
<input type="text" id="address" class="form-control" pattern=".{5,}"
title="We Need Your City and Zipcode to proceed."
placeholder="ie. New York 25317" required>
```

You can put any 5 characters in and the form works but my app is relying on the zipcode for a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern should be:
"\b\d{5}\b"

This will make sure that only strings which contain a substring of exactly 5 digits will be allowed. The \b is a word boundary checker that will keep it from approving 6-digit (or more) strings.

If you are not worried about "more than 5 digits" then go with: "\d{5}" for the pattern.